# Command "File.AddexistingItem" is not valid

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am curious about why wouldn't this command work?

```
File.AddExistingItem
```

Since it's stated in MSDN library and it has its own chapter about it!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h4c0t7y.aspx

I am using VS2015
1. Open the IDE's command window by View->Other Window->Command Window
(or simply by shortcut key: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Type `File.AddExistingItem Whatever_Valid_CSHARP_Filepath` 
[image: no auto-completion]
(As you can see there is no auto-completion for File.AddExistingItem)

3.It comes out `"Command "File.AddexistingItem" is not valid."`
But the similar command File.AddExistingProject works adding *.csproj 
[image: using File.AddExistingProject works, and no "Command xxx is not valid" coming out]
(using File.AddExistingProject works, and no "Command xxx is not valid" coming out)

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?
And How can I fix it? If it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I added a bug report about this to Microsoft Developer Community (aka User Voice)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/536640/fileaddexistingitem-does-not-appear-visual-studio.html